# c++ class instance memory layout once again

Tags: c++, memory, layout, shared-libraries

I know that this question has been asked previously, but before you give me a minus and report repeated question, ponder a while on this:

In all previous answers everybody says that object memory layout is compiler dependent. How is it then, that shared libraries (*.dll, *.so) can export and import c++ classes, and they can definitely be combined even if coming from different compilers? Consider a DirectX application written under mingw. DirectX was compiled using MSVC++, so how do those environments agree on memory layout? I know that DirectX relies heavily on C++ classes and polymorphism.

Asking differently: let's say that I have a chosen architecture (eg. Windows, intel x86) and I am trying to write a new compiler. How do I know how to access class instance (vtable, member fields) provided by .dll lib compiled by another compiler? Or is it simply like that: M$ has written VC++, and since then it is unwritten standard, and every other compiler does it the same "for compatibility reasons"? And what about linux or other OS-es?

EDIT:

OK I admit, the example with DirectX was bad because of COM specification...

Another example: QT. I am using QT with mingw, but I know there are also available MSVC versions. I don't know if the difference is only in headers, or if shared libs (dll-s) are also different. If they are, does it mean that I have to distribute my app with qt libs included, so if anybody happens to have ones for a different compiler it will not get mixed-up? (Nice memory and code sharing then, right?). Or are they the same and there is some unwritten law about it anyway?

EDIT2:

I have installed a different qt version (msvc 2010) just to see what is and isn't shared. Seems that shared (are they really shared then) libraries are different. Seems that I really have to provide qt-libs with my app then... And this is no small thing (eg. QtGui 8-9MB). What about other, smaller libs, whose authors weren't so kind to provide versions for other compilers? Does it mean that I am stuck with their original compiler? What if I want to use two different libs that were compiled by different compilers?

Comment: The layout of vtables is quite a bit older than Visual C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you're asking about an ABI.

In some cases (e.g., on the Itanium) there's a document that specifies the ABI, and essentially everybody follows the document.

In the case of DirectX, it's a bit the same: Microsoft has published specs for COM, so anybody who follows those specs can get interop with essentially any COM object (within reason -- a 64-bit compiler probably isn't going to work with a 16-bit COM object written for Windows 3.1).

For most other things, you're more or less on your own to figure things out. There's often at least a little published in the way of documentation, but at least in my experience it often skims over some details that end up important, isn't updated entirely dependably, and in some cases is just plain wrong. In most cases, it's also poorly organized so it's pretty much up to you to glean what you can from wherever you can find it, and when you run out of information (or patience) do some reverse engineering to fill in the missing parts.

Edit: For non-COM things like Qt libraries, you have a couple of choices. One is to link to the Qt libraries statically, so the Qt code you need gets linked directly into your executable. If you want to use a DLL, then yes, you're *pretty* much stuck with distributing one with your app that's going to be specific to the compiler you use to generate the application itself. A different compiler (or even a different version or set of compilation flags with the same compiler) will generally require a different DLL (possibly the same source code, but built to accommodate the compiler change).

There are exceptions to this, but they're pretty much like I've outlined above. For example, the Intel compiler for Windows normally uses Microsoft's standard library, and can use most (if not all) other libraries built for Microsoft's compiler as well. This is pretty much because Intel has bent over backward to assure that their compiler uses the same calling convention, name mangling scheme, etc., as Microsoft's though. It works because they put in a lot of effort to make it work, not because of any unwritten law, or anything like that.

Comment: "not because of any unwritten law, or anything like that". What you wrote seems to me like unwritten law: "do it as MSVC or perish" then... I suspect that mingw guys did exactly the same as Intel for similar reasons.

Comment: In general COM specifies most of the C++ ABI, and any compiler on Windows will strive to be compatible with this ABI. Once the ABI is specified, the big problem remains the standard library, and here you can see that even dlls compiled with the same compiler in two different configurations cannot pass around `std::...` objects.

Comment: Ok how do I know then that my configuration is ok? Many libs doesn't specify that. Especially smaller ones, for specific purposes (eg. image processing) where programmers themselves were more focused on functionality and not low-level ABI compatibility (if they were even aware of the problem). This scenario is a bit of stretch, but I still say that this is a BIG problem for C++ in practical use,

Comment: @j_kubik: What it means is that C libraries could be distributed as object code, but C++ libraries mostly need to be distributed as source code. Then again, templates pretty much have to be distributed as source code in any case.

Comment: Are at least C-only libraries free of this burden, and cross-compiler compatible? I expect some problems with calling convetions (or are those at least standarized somehow?) An now with advent of C++11 and extern templates, I expect to see also lot's of template-like code not being distributed as source.

Comment: @j_kubik: C is a lot less of a problem anyway. This is especially true if (for example) you use `stdcall` calling convention on Windows. I don't expect template code to be distributed without source. Most compilers simply require source.

Comment: @JerryCoffin 'stdcall' is fine, but again: what really is 'stdcall' and who says it? What is the standard on calling convetions? Who says what really happens in asm code uder the hood?

Comment: @j_kubik: `stdcall` is what MS says it is. No, there's not really any single standard for calling conventions. In most cases, anybody trying for compatibility imitates what the OS uses, because everything else on the same OS has to be compatible with the OS.

Comment: Hope I am not boring, but just another question to have it summarized? Is there some way to determine at least with which ABI given lib was compiled, given only the library file? I mean by checking some header fields in it, and not by examinig the code and trying to guess. If it is possible then at least I could check the ABI and try to add some compatibility to layer to it,.

Comment: @j_kubik: As a rule no, at least not on Windows.

Comment: Ok thanks. This response answers fully to my quiestion, so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

DirectX is a COM-based technology and that is why it can be used in C with various compilers. Under the hood COM interface is a C-like structure which emulates the VMT.

Technically, DirectX has a midl-autogenerated C++ interface, but the general assertion that one can use classes exported in .dlls across different compilers is wrong.

Edit1:

QT dlls built using MSVC won't be compatible with the ones built by gcc, unfortunately, because of the natural reasons: different C++ compiler - different ABI and different run-time library (mingw uses older MSVCRT and that is why pure-C .dlls can be consumed in MSVC and vice versa). Some compilers incidentally or partially intentionally match their ABIs, but this is definitely not the case with MSVC/gcc. QT can also be built as a static library, so to redistribute things one might just link statically.

The name mangling for C++ classes in DLLs depends largely on the compiler front-end used. Many commercial compilers from well-known companies use EDG's C++ parser and that is why the class names an overloaded functions have similar or matching signatures.

Edit2:

"What if I want to use two different libs that were compiled by different compilers?"

If you desperately need some specific functionality from both libraries (I mean some concrete operation, not the framework overall), then the way to go without having the library's source code is to write some wrapper and compile this wrapper to the C-style .dll.

Think of this like having "two different C++-es, C++-1 and C++-2". The problem with ABI/Runtime is no different from using Pascal code from C or linking with some older Fortran libs.

Comment: "Under the hood COM interface is a C-like structure which emulates the VMT" - and it just so happens to be also how MSVC lays-out all it's classes, am I right? ;)

Comment: @j_kubik: Most of its classes, anyway, yes. If you use multiple inheritance, VC++ can lay out the classes a couple of different ways, but at least if memory serves, COM doesn't support MI so none of them correspond directly to a COM object layout.

Comment: So for Windows at least I can simply either try my best to MSVC compatibile (which MSVC then; they are not even compatibile with one-another), or forget about my own compiler cause nobody will ever use it cause lots of useful libs not being compatible, right? Are at least C-only libraries free of this burden, and cross-compiler compatible? I expect some problems with calling convetions (or are those at least standarized somehow?)

Comment: The calling convention compatibility allows you to use .dlls (which are standardized) compiled with different C toolchains.